# comparision between django model version control packages

Tags: python, django

I need to implement Django model history version & compare view.

I found there are packages like **django-reversion**, **django-simple-history**, **django-revisions** to implement model history version and **django-reversion-compare** for compare view. My requirement focuses mainly on **implementing version history & compare view outside admin**.

Can someone share the feedback on these packages? I found few references like http://treyhunner.com/2011/09/django-and-model-history/, but it's still not clear to me. I am interested to know the **ease & limitations** of implementing these packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `django-reversion` + `django-reversion-compare`. I have been using `django-reversion` for at least 5 years and `django-reversion-compare` is just an add-on for `django-reversion`, which makes it possible to compare different revisions of the same object/record.

Additionally see the following [grid](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/versioning/).

Comment: Thanks Arthur ! I was aware of django-reversion + django-reversion-compare, but few links suggested django-simple-history better than django-reversion; does that mean django-reversion + django-reversion-compare is the only option to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: I honestly didn't try those, but added a link to a feature grid to my answer. 58 people have mentioned that they are using `django-reversion`, which is a good sign.

Comment: Thanks Arthur ! I will share my findings in case, I will try anything new :)

Comment: @Ankit What can you say about your use of this library after this time?

Comment: It seems django-reversion now requires python 3.6, which is just out of reach for those of us using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @bparker: Not at all. Use `dead-snakes`.